# tikz multi corners arrow looping around diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, draw

I'm trying to use tikz to draw algorithm diagrams.
Assuming we have nodes A, B and C linked by arrows like so: A-->B-->C

How to make an arrow that goes from the bottom of C to the top of A by going around the whole diagram.
This is what I got with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, text centered,    
draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
\node (A) [process] {A}; 
\node (B) [process, below of=A] {B};
\node (C) [process, below of=B] {C};
\draw [arrow] (A) -- (B);
\draw [arrow] (B) -- (C);
\draw [arrow] (C) -- (A);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get:

[image: What I have]

And this is what I'd like to get:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can add a "fake node" and use `node1 -| node2` or `node1 |- node2` for pathes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, text centered,    
draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
\node (A) [process] {A}; 
\node (B) [process, below of=A] {B};
\node (C) [process, below of=B] {C};
\draw [arrow] (A) -- (B);
\draw [arrow] (B) -- (C);
\draw [arrow] (C) |-([shift={(3mm,-3mm)}]C.south east)-- ([shift={(3mm,3mm)}]A.north east)-|(A);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```